# Why do I configure devtools as inline-source-map or the js.map file fails to load?

Tags: node.js, webpack, rxjs, electron

These are relevant webpack configs:

```js
module.exports = {
    target: "electron-renderer",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    ...
}
```

It correctly bootstraps the sourceMappingURL of the element-plugs framework.

However, it does not properly bootstrap the sourceMappingURL of the rxjs framework.

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:9000/home/aszswaz/project/zhiweidata/electron-anyproxy/electron-anyproxy-new/node_modules/rxjs/util/AnimationFrame.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:9000/home/aszswaz/project/zhiweidata/electron-anyproxy/electron-anyproxy-new/node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/AnimationFrameScheduler.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:9000/home/aszswaz/project/zhiweidata/electron-anyproxy/electron-anyproxy-new/node_modules/rxjs/operators.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:9000/home/aszswaz/project/zhiweidata/electron-anyproxy/electron-anyproxy-new/node_modules/uri-js/dist/es5/uri.all.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

webpackage version: 5.70.0

webpackage cli version: 4.9.2

webpack-dev-server version: 4.7.4